# Creating a new array containing all the elements of the original array that are located before the first negative element

Tags: c++

This is what I want: Based on the original array, create a new array containing all the elements of the original array that are located before the first negative element. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {

  const int N = 1000;
  int a[N];
  int k;
  bool f = false;
  vector<int> b;
  cout << "Input size of array: ";
  cin >> k;
  cout << "Input elements: ";
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) cin >> a[i];
  cout << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
  {
    if (a[i] < 0 && !f)
    {
      f = true;
    }
    if (f) b.push_back(a[i]);
  }
  if (!f) cout << "No negative \n >> ";
  else for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) cout << b[i] << " ";
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

I output ARTER the first negative, but need BEFORE the first negative.

Comment: In `if (f) b.push_back(a[i]);` think about when the condition will be true, and whether you want the code to execute in that case. Even better, use a debugger to see what the state of the variables is when executing.

Comment: naming variables is important. If your `bool f = false;` was named `bool do_copy_elements_to_the_other_vector = false;` it would be easier to see why it should start out as `true` not `false`

Comment: Deleting the portion of your question that makes it understandable to future readers is very much frowned upon here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using `f` as a flag which is initially false. This means you didn't get any negative yet. When The `f` will be true then you can say that you got at least one negative number and as f is true you will not push any elements further.

So, You should push in the vector until you get at least 1 negative number. Which means you have to push only when the flag is false.

So your push statement should look like this:

```cpp
if (!f) b.push_back(a[i]);
```